# Why am I getting the error: CASE: syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why am I getting the error: ' CASE: syntax error' ? Attempting to retrieve records in sqlite3.

```
SELECT c.Region, c.City, c.PostalCode
CASE 
WHEN c.Region = e.Region THEN c.Region
        CASE
        WHEN c.City = e.City THEN c.City
            CASE
     WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode THEN c.PostalCode
     ELSE 'Null'
     END
            WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode THEN c.PostalCode
            ELSE 'Null'
            END
        ELSE 'Null'
        END
ELSE 'Null'
END
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID INNER JOIN employees e ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: there are three case statement started but you have four end clause

Comment: What a mess. What are you trying to do with these case _expressions_?

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with [c#] and [.net]

Comment: `WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode THEN c.PostalCode` appears two times, is it intended?

Answer (score 2):

You need a single case expression as follows:

```
CASE 
WHEN c.Region = e.Region THEN c.Region
WHEN c.City = e.City THEN c.City
WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode THEN c.PostalCode
END
```

This assumes that all the columns in `THEN` has same data type.

Comment: `ELSE 'Null'` maybe?

Comment: Null as a string? Then yes. But if OP actually means NULL then not needed.

Comment: I don't know tbh, it was just to make it consistent with what OP wrote, but you're right, maybe it's better to let it return `NULL` by default

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 ELSE statements for 3 CASE statements.
the correct script is :

```
SELECT
c.Region,
c.City,
c.PostalCode 
CASE 
    WHEN c.Region = e.Region 
    THEN c.Region 
    CASE 
        WHEN c.City = e.City 
        THEN c.City 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode 
            THEN c.PostalCode 
        ELSE 'Null' END
        WHEN c.PostalCode = e.PostalCode 
        THEN c.PostalCode 
    ELSE 'Null' 
    END 
ELSE 'Null' 
END 
FROM
  customers c LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID INNER JOIN employees e ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Is it  even valid?? Syntax after THEN seems incorrect.